# How to Solve ODE as a Bessel Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Given an ODE as follows:
$$xy''+y'-y=0.$$
I have no problem in finding the general solution using the Frobenius method, but I'm curious on how to solve this as a Bessel equation:
$$x^2y''+(1-2p)xy'+\bigl(-\lambda^2q^2x^{2q}+p^2-\nu^2q^2\bigr)y=0.$$
This Bessel equation is the more general version of the modified Bessel equation, where $\lambda$, $p$, and $q$ are some complex parameters. Wolfram gives a general solution:
$$y=c_1I_0\bigl(2\sqrt{x}\bigr)+c_2K_0\bigl(2\sqrt{x}\bigr).$$
How to get this result?

Comment: If you don't mind working backward from the provided solution, you immediately get the [modified Bessel equation $(n=0)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html) upon substituting $z=2\sqrt x\iff x=\frac{z^2}4$.

Comment: I see! That's the one thing I've been wondering about, so if I don't want to do the instant parametric Bessel equation, I should transform the ODE in the first place by substituting $z=2\sqrt{x}$. Thank you @user170231!

Comment: BTW, according to what I have read in the Wolfram documentation that you've sent, the solution is not necessarily in the form of modified Bessel function. If I choose to write the solution in the form of Bessel function, it'll be $$y=c_1J_0\bigl(-2i\sqrt{x}\bigr)+c_2Y_0\bigl(-2i\sqrt{x}\bigr).$$ Was this correct?

Comment: Yes, that form is equivalent. See the relations listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) to see how to convert between each pair of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make the variable change

$$\left[x = \frac{z^2}4 \implies \frac{dx}{dz} = \frac z2\right] \iff \left[z=2\sqrt x \implies \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac1{\sqrt x}\right]$$

By the chain rule,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{dy}{dz} \cdot \frac{dz}{dx} \\
&= \frac2z \, \frac{dy}{dz} \\[2ex]
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &= \frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dz} \cdot \frac{dz}{dx} \\
&= \left(\frac2z \, \frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac2{z^2}\,\frac{dy}{dz}\right) \, \frac2z \\
&= \frac4{z^2} \, \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} - \frac4{z^3} \, \frac{dy}{dz}
\end{align*}$$

Substituting these into the original ODE gives

$$\frac{z^2}4 \left(\frac4{z^2} \, \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} - \frac4{z^3} \, \frac{dy}{dz}\right) + \frac2z \, \frac{dy}{dz} - y = 0 \\
\implies \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} + \frac1z \, \frac{dy}{dz} - y = 0 \\
\implies z^2 \, \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} + z\,\frac{dy}{dz} - z^2 y = 0$$

This is the [modified Bessel equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html) with $n=0$; from its general solution we can recover the original ODE's solution, in agreement with Wolfram|Alpha's.

$$\begin{align*}
y\left(\frac{z^2}4\right) &= c_1 J_0\left(-i\frac{z^2}4\right) + c_2 Y_0\left(-i\frac{z^2}4\right) \\
&= c_1 I_0\left(\frac{z^2}4\right) + c_2 K_0\left(\frac{z^2}4\right) \\[2ex]
\implies y(x) &= c_1 J_0\left(-2i\sqrt x\right) + c_2 Y_0\left(-2i\sqrt x\right) \\
&= \boxed{c_1 I_0\left(2\sqrt x\right) + c_2 K_0\left(2\sqrt x\right)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Your step-by-step explanations are very clear and somewhat easy to grasp. Thanks a lot.