# Prove that $y = J_0(2 \sqrt x)$ is a solution of $x\ddot y + \dot y + y = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

I'm been trying to prove this result about Bessel functions but I didn't work it out. My question is how to prove by direct substitution that $$y = J_0(2 \sqrt x)$$ is a solution to $$x\cdot \ddot y + \dot y + y = 0$$.

Comment: Hint: $${J_\nu }' (z)=\frac{1}{2}J_{\nu-1}(z)-\frac{1}{2}J_{\nu+1}(z)$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696598/how-to-solve-ode-as-a-bessel-equation/